# Uncheck all other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to clear all other checkboxes when a user clicks a checkbox. Pretty much the same behavior as a radio button. User clicks checkbox 'A' and checkboxes 'B' and 'C' are both unchecked. I am using jquery but I can't figure out how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Here are how the checkboxes are set u:

```
    <div class="sales_block_one">
<span class="sales_box_option_set"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="exopt10i11553501716" name="optset[0][id]" /><label for="exopt10i11553501716">Test  + &pound;100.00</label></span> 
<span class="sales_box_option_set"><input type="checkbox" value="2" id="exopt11i21553501716" name="optset[1][id]" /><label for="exopt11i21553501716">Test  + &pound; 200.00</label></span> 
<span class="sales_box_option_set"><input type="checkbox" value="3" id="exopt12i31553501716" name="optset[2][id]" /><label for="exopt12i31553501716">Test 3 + &pound;400.00</label></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: why you're not use radiobutton? that's a simple way.

Comment: @klox - maybe the OP want the check ( ☑ ) on the design ;)

Comment: Yes, I know radio buttons would be ideal but they can't be used in application.

Comment: Why is that voted down? I mean its a weird usecase (unless its something like "non of the above" or something ... bu even still) , but judging from the Text he seams to be aware of the fact that hes copying radio-box behavior to some extend.

Comment: using siblings solves the problem; radio button behavior. But what's the behavior when you check/uncheck B and C(other checkboxes)

Comment: @Klox: Client has specifically requested checkboxes. I explained and he doesn't care.

Comment: This question is particularly relevant due to an ASP.NET bug/limitation on  RadioButton controls in different naming containers. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316495/en-us

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if all the checkboxes are siblings, it's just like this,

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){

   if (this.checked) {
      $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
   }

});
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/8p6kd/)

Well, if you really want to copy the behavior of the radio button, simple as this,

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
      this.checked = true;
      $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);     
});
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/jhEVF/)

---

siblings is when the elements has one same parent/container.

sample

```
<div>

<input type="checkbox" /><label>A</label>
<input type="checkbox" /><label>B</label>
<input type="checkbox" /><label>C</label>
<input type="checkbox" />​<label>D</label>

</div>
```

in that, `<input>`s and `<label>`s are siblings.

---

In your case, which it's not siblings, you can do it this way,

```
$('.sales_block_one :checkbox').change(function() {
    var $self = this; // save the current object - checkbox that was clicked.
    $self.checked = true; // make the clicked checkbox checked no matter what.
    $($self).closest('span') // find the closest parent span...
        .siblings('span.sales_box_option_set') // get the siblings of the span
        .find(':checkbox').attr('checked',false); // then find the checbox inside each span and then uncheck it.
});​
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/9gLw9/)

[more about traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: Dumb question: what constitutes siblings? I googled to no avail.

Comment: Ahh, I see - is there a way to do this in a case w/o siblings then?

Comment: I added the HTML set up to my OP

Comment: I added another `crazy demo` rrrr... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#checkboxA").click(function() {
    var checkedStatus = this.checked;
    $("#checkboxB_And_C_Selector").each(function() {
        this.checked = !checkedStatus;
    });
});
```

Comment: this won't exactly work as expected because it will cause all other boxes to be checked when you click to uncheck any of the boxes.